# Delete and reuse first auto increment ids from InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

English is not my first language, so I apologize in advance for any grammar mistake.

I have the following MySQL tables (simplified for easily understanding):

```
users (InnoDB - utf8_general_ci):
- usr_Id: int(11) unsigned Auto_Increment
- usr_Username: varchar(50)
- usr_Password: varchar(50)

messages (InnoDB - utf8_general_ci):
- msg_Id: int(11) unsigned Auto_Increment
- msg_UserId: int(11) unsigned
- msg_Date: datetime
- msg_Subject: varchar(50)
- msg_Text: varchar(1024)
```

And there is a simple web interface (PHP) where users log in to check their messages:

```
SELECT msg_Id, msg_Subject FROM messages WHERE msg_UserId = <Logged User Id> ORDER BY msg_Date DESC;
```

Once user clicks in the message subject on the list, it shows a popup with the message:

```
SELECT msg_Text FROM messages WHERE msg_Id = <Id From Clicked Message>;
```

Every day at 4am a cronjob automatically delete all messages older than 3 months:

```
DELETE FROM messages WHERE msg_Date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

So, here is my problem: This system is in testing for about 5 months now, with less than 100 users, and msg_Id is already 91451 ! When in real usage, I am expecting at least 2000-5000 users!

Once older messages are automatically deleted and I do not use msg_Id for linking different tables, I am wondering if I could "reuse" the first ids after a while, maybe blocking server for some minutes for doing a process to "reset" the ids? Or maybe there is an easier way? Please, what options do I have?

Thank you!

Comment: There's really no reason to. Just let that number continue to increment. There is little to no chance it will ever reach the limits of that column.

Comment: As long as there are records with higher auto increment values, the server will not be able to reuse the lower values. Plus Dave is right, just check the max number for bigint...

Comment: `auto_increment` MUST not be reused. Not *should not*, **must not**. It's used internally by MySQL to write data. There's nothing wrong with having gaps. `auto_increment` is **not for sequential numbering**, it's used to provide a **unique** number. For that, it uses sequential increment. If your `auto_increment` is regular `int`, you have 4.2 billion numbers at your disposal. If that's not enough, you can increase it to `bigint`. If you continually inserted 1000 users per-second for next few thousand years, you wouldn't exceed `bigint`.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! @N.B., do you think I can have a significant storage impact on changing `msg_id` from `int` to `bigint` and having some millions records? What if `msg_id` was not auto_increment, can you think in an easy way to reuse ids? Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer your question because you want to *reuse* the numbers that are lost, and all people commenting here are telling you **not to**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even think about reusing `AUTO_INCREMENT` values; it is not worth the hassle.  Don't even think about reinventing this wheel.  There are many good features built into it.

Do some math.  If you think you might exceed 4 billion rows, change `msg_id` from `INT UNSIGNED` to `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.  1 million `BIGINTs` will take 4MB more than `INT`.  (Or more if there are secondary indexes.)

(Optional)  Don't clutter SQL by prefixing column names with the table name.)

Consider using `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(msg_Date))` to help with efficiently dropping old data.

Do the math!  91451 * 5000/100 / 5 = only 1M rows/month.  It would take 3 *centuries* to get to 4 billion even without reusing ids.

91K rows is a "small" table.  A table with a billion rows is "big", but doable.

Indexes needed:

With partitioning (see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)):

```
PRIMARY KEY(UserId, Date, msg_id),
INDEX(msg_id)
```

Without partitioning:

```
PRIMARY KEY(Date, msg_id),
INDEX(msg_id),
INDEX(UserId, Date)
```

These will efficiently support the `SELECTs` you provided.

Caution:  Some day there will be a user with thousands of messages.  Your first `SELECT` may be slower than desired, or may cause trouble in the UI.  My choice of indexes will help some.